# Compare multiple values that need to be 1:1 to comprise a full order

Tags: excel, math

I'm sure this is an easy one but a solution isn't coming to mind.

I have inventory values for a variety of products, but a shipment requires a minimum value of 1 for each product of that shipment for the shipment to be possible.

What is the easiest way to verify if the shipment is possible, and how many of that shipment can be put together based on current inventory values?

```
Example data:
Name      | Quantity
Product 1 | 250
Product 2 | 100
Product 3 | 300
```

- Shipment 1 requires 1:1 of Product 1 and 2.
- Shipment 2 requires 1:1 of all 3 products.

How do I calculate how many of each shipment can be put together given the current inventory levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Quantity is column a and products are on rows 1, 2, and 3:

Shipment 1: `=IF(A1>0&A2>0,MIN(A1,A2),0)`
Shipment 2: `=IF(A1>0&A2>0&A3>0,MIN(A1,A2,A3),0)`

Comment: Ah, the MIN function! Thanks a bunch!